# grep command on multiple lines (not multiline grep)

Tags: unix, grep

Trying to figure out how to write a command across multiple lines because the real one is way to long for a prompt (4200 chars), so I tried this example:

Made a test file that contained the following 3 lines:

`some thing`
`some`
`thing`

When I do this grep:
`grep "some thing" test`

I get the expected result of:
`some thing`

But when I do this grep: 
`grep "some \`
`thing" test`

I get the unexpected result of:
`some thing`
`thing`

Almost as if it ran the grep twice, once for "some " and once for "thing".  Is there any way to properly use the `\` to combine the 2 to where the result is like the first grep?

Comment: Just re-reading this ... what _exactly_ is your expected output?

Comment: @steve I'd like to be the same as a one liner (so the first example, only `some thing` returned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like this did it:
`grep "some \`
`|thing" test.txt`

Produced: `some thing`

Same as: `grep "some thing" test.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of **grep**, you have to use **pcregrep**, then you will be able to use new lines in pattern by **-M** option.

In your example it will be like:

```
pcregrep -M 'some\nthing' test
```

Comment: + cool! With -z -o you can also make grep do it (see bellow).

Answer (score 1):

Using -zPo you can make grep behave multilingual:

```
grep -zPo 'some\nthing' test
```